# Fill column with random numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 580 M records. My code below seems to time out after more than an hour and SQL Developer becomes unresponsive. Is there a more efficient way to add a column of random numbers?

```
create table bigTable (
  ID_KEY CHAR(64 BYTE),
  randNum decimal(4,3)
);

-- insert ID_KEY value for 580M records (not shown)

UPDATE /*+PARALLEL(16)*/ bigTable 
SET randNum = CAST(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,1) AS DECIMAL(4,3));
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Does this table have any indices on it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen At the moment no, but I could create one.

Comment: OK...I asked because I thought that perhaps an index needed to be rebuilt along the way.  The answer below looks promising though.

Comment: So, this huge table is not partitioned? It has a string identifier (a GUID?) rather than a monotonically incrementing sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I offer you use CTAS for such big data. 
for example you can write

```
   create table bigTable as
          select ID_KEY , CAST(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,1) AS DECIMAL(4,3)) randNum
     from YOUR_TABLE_WHERE_ID_COMES_FROM;
```

I think your problem possible comes from management of REDO files, keep ing changes log for such big data may cause a problem, although it depends of your redo file size HDD write speed and many other reasons.

About @MarcinJ answer , using many commits may cause another problem, time to flush data to tables after commit makes oralce to write data to hdd, rewrite redo and so on, all that may increase time of execution.

Comment: Wow, that's a very interesting and simple solution. It also matches very well to my situation where I'm creating this table specifically to add a random number column. Essentially, you're saying that creating the random number column at the same time when the table is created will be much faster. That eliminates a step for me as well. Could you comment more about why this is faster and a maybe a few more details about how much faster it may be?

Comment: @Bobby: DDL statements don't create (=write) UNDO (rollback) information which is a major performance bottleneck when doing large UPDATEs (or DELETEs).

Comment: At least, insert works faster then insert+update, second `create table ` is DDL and CTAS used for fast reorganization of big tables, use can add `parallel` hint to `select ` inside CTAS. I think this article will useful for you [link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_create_table_select_ctas.htm)

Comment: This solution took 40 minutes to execute. I canceled the one below after waiting for more than an hour so I can't compare it precisely.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely taking this log because you're trying to do everything in a single transaction and this means it will become very big. If possible, you can try updating the table in batches, e.g. 1 million rows at a time. Then you can loop until no records have an empty randNum. Something like:

```
DECLARE
   rowsAffected INTEGER := 1;
BEGIN
   WHILE rowsAffected <> 0 LOOP
      UPDATE bigTable
         SET randNum = CAST(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,1) AS DECIMAL(4,3))
       WHERE randNum IS NULL
         AND rownum < 1000000;

      rowsAffected := sql%rowcount;

      COMMIT;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Try it out first with a single query, I don't have access to an Oracle db at the moment to test it.

Comment: Thanks! It's running now and I'll post an update later.

Comment: Doing batched commits doesn't improve performance. [Quote from Tom Lane](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=issue-frequent-commit-statements) "*slows you down, yes, that is right, SLOWS YOU DOWN -- makes you run SLOOOWWWWEEERRR

o doesn't conserve any resources, in fact, it consumes more (you generate MORE redo)*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I'm not sure that batches of 1,000,000 rows count as "frequent" commits.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: but still, those commits won't improve the performance in any way. The only thing they prevent is a "rollback to small" error.

Comment: This will not improve performance, in fact performance will degrade. Each loop has to read all the previously updated records. The first loop will update 1000000 rows. The second loop will have to read those 1000000 rows before it can start updating the next 1000000 rows. The third loop will have to read 2000000 rows before it can start updating. So each loop will be progressively slower than the previous iteration.

Comment: The idea is not to make this faster, it's to make it manageable. With one huge transaction it's either all or nothing, and according to the question, it's nothing because the client stops responding. With batches you can at least make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command before the `UPDATE`, to fully parallelize the SQL statement:

```
alter session enable parallel dml;
```

If you're using 12c or later you can change that setting in a hint, like this:

```
UPDATE /*+PARALLEL(16) ENABLE_PARALLEL_DML*/ ...
```

Seyran's answer is still the most *efficient* way to make a large update.  And you could make his answer even faster by adding `PARALLEL` hints and a `NOLOGGING` option.

But if you're dealing with large data sets you might as well learn now the importance of fully parallelizing statements.  The original `UPDATE` is hardly using parallelism at all.  The lack of parallelism is confusing, because you might see lots of parallel sessions in use in `GV$PX_PROCESS`, and you may even see a few `PX` operations in an execution plan like this:

```
Plan hash value: 1905498248

------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name     |
------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT      |          |
|   1 |  UPDATE               | BIGTABLE |
|   2 |   PX COORDINATOR      |          |
|   3 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)| :TQ10000 |
|   4 |     PX BLOCK ITERATOR |          |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| BIGTABLE |
------------------------------------------
```

Unfortunately, Oracle can sometimes *allocate* parallel processes but not meaningfully *use* them in parallel.

A fully parallelized statement should have a `PX` operation above the DML operation.  You want to see an execution plan like the one below.  It's only slightly different than the execution plan above, but it may run almost 16 times faster.

```
Plan hash value: 1693571574

------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name     |
------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT      |          |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR       |          |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM) | :TQ10000 |
|   3 |    UPDATE             | BIGTABLE |
|   4 |     PX BLOCK ITERATOR |          |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| BIGTABLE |
------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score -3):

**For Interger**

```
DECLARE @RandomNumber AS  INT
 Select @RandomNumber=  FLOOR(RAND()*(2500-10+1))+1000;
PRINT @RandomNumber

Insert into Student(RollNumber)values(@RandomNumber)
```

**TIP:** This formula would generate a random integer number that is >= 1000 and <= 2500.

You can Changes values as per you need and You can also Genrate Float and Double Numbers

**Thank You!!!!**

Comment: The question is for Oracle, so this syntax is not valid.

Comment: It's irrelevant if it works on SQL Server - it will not work on Oracle. The question is tagged for Oracle not SQL Server.

Comment: Apart from the syntax problems, it doesn't address the actual problem as it only also inserts a single row into a table. It does not give an answer on how to speed up the UPDATE of 580 million rows.

Comment: For future reference the `[sql]` tag simply indicates that the question is about **the SQL language** - DML, DDL and so forth,. Questions about MS SQL Server will be tagged `[sql-server]`.